# Using Vault with multiple dynamic namespaces in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Is it possible to share a ServiceAccount between namespaces or somehow start a pod with a ServiceAccount from a different namespace?

We are looking to use vault to store common secret data between dynamic development environments.  Following the very good walk though [HERE](https://medium.com/@gmaliar/dynamic-secrets-on-kubernetes-pods-using-vault-35d9094d169) we were able to authenticate and pull secrets for a single namespace.  However in our use case we will be creating a new namespace for each development environment during it's lifetime.

If possible we would like to avoid having to also configure vault with a new auth backend for each namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create the Vault role, you can [configure `bound_service_account_namespaces` to be the special value `*`](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/kubernetes/index.html#bound_service_account_namespaces), and allow a fixed service account name from any namespace.  To adapt the "create role" [example from the documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes.html#configuration):

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/demo \
    bound_service_account_names=vault-auth \
    bound_service_account_namespaces='*' \
    policies=default \
    ttl=1h
```

You have to recreate the Kubernetes service account in every namespace, and it must have the exact name specified in the role.  However, the Kubernetes service account is a single k8s object and it's not any harder than the Deployments, Services, ConfigMaps, and Secrets you already have; this pattern doesn't require any Vault reconfiguration.

(If you're using a templating tool like Helm, the service account can't follow a naming convention like `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}`: Vault doesn't appear to have any sort of pattern matching on this name.)

Comment: This worked perfectly, I completely missed that part of the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Service Accounts are namespaced therefore not shared , so you may copy the token from one account to another , but that is not the recommneded way.

```
C02W84XMHTD5:kubernetes-gitlab iahmad$ kubectl api-resources --namespaced | grep service
serviceaccounts             sa                                       true         ServiceAccount
services                    svc                                      true         Service
C02W84XMHTD5:kubernetes-gitlab iahmad$
```

If you want to share a secret or account the way you  are trying to do , then there is no need to use vault at all.

You may just need to automate this process , instead of sharing accounts.

Comment: I was about to implement it this way until a colleague of mine pointed to the accepted answer above, worked like a charm.